# Pandas: Determine which rows are connected by a matching value in the next

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

I have a dataframe like so:

```
      J1    J2    J3    J4
0     551    5    552   553
1     551   554    2     5
2      2    554   555   556
3      7     6    557   558
4     559    9    560   561
```

The goal is to determine which rows are connected to one another. For example: rows 0, 1, and 2 have a matching value that connects it to the next (551 in row 0 and 1, and 554 in row 1 and 2). Once that is determined, I need to isolate those rows into its own separate chunk of data. It should work for any row in the dataframe, not necessarily just the next row. I can't quite figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you dataset is small, you can use numpy broadcasting to perform all comparisons:

The code below gives you the number of connected rows (I added an extra connected row for the example):

```
a = df.values

b = (a==a[:,None]).sum(2)
np.fill_diagonal(b, 0)

df['connected'] = b.sum(0)
```

output:

```
     0    1    2    3  connected
0  551    5  552  553          1
1  551  554    2    5          3
2    2  554  555  556          1
3    7    6  557  558          0
4  559    9  560  561          0
5  500    0    2    0          1
```

Comment: I guess my problem is that each row actually represents a rectangle with 4 points. Now, picture many separate rectangles each broken up into 'n' rectangles. I need to group together the smaller rectangles to form the single, large one for each of the many pieces (say 150 rectangles sliced into 2/3 pieces each or something). So the output should be one chunk of data with the joint/point ID's for each overall piece. Not sure if that makes sense, or if it's even possible.

Answer (score -1):

Finding the connected **successive** rows:

You can compare with the next row using `shift`+`any`:

```
mask = df.eq(df.shift(-1)).any(1)
df['connected'] = mask|mask.shift()
```

output:

```
    J1   J2   J3   J4  connected
0  551    5  552  553       True
1  551  554    2    5       True
2    2  554  555  556       True
3    7    6  557  558      False
4  559    9  560  561      False
```

Comment: This is true, but what if 10 rows down, there is another row that contains the value "551". How can I connect that row to rows 0, 1, and 2 and store it as a separate list? I need to do this for each instance that this occurs. It should search any of the rows in the table for a matching value.

Comment: How big is your real dataset? What you want to do requires to compare all combinations of rows, which can quickly get difficult. There are different strategies depending on the size of the data.

Comment: The dataset is just, [550 rows x 5 columns]. So nothing too intense. I don't care about efficiency in this case, because this code will basically be a 1 time use thing.

Comment: @largerod I provided another answer, let me know if this works for you.